# No service principal found for application ID: "ddbf3205-c6bd-46ae-8127-60eb93363864"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure, azure-batch

Terraform fails to find service principal associated with Azure Batch if Batch Account hasn't been created yet under given Azure tenant. Unfortunately, I need that SPN before Batch gets created in order to grant AzBatch Contributor role on subscription level (required when UserSubscription model is being used).

Do you know if there's any way to force AAD to register enterprise application for Azure Batch first?

Here's part of my terraform that fails on pristine tenant but works on one where AzBatch has been provisioned already:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}

# following line will fail
data "azuread_service_principal" "batch_spn" {
  client_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.AzureBatch
}

# but it's needed for this to work:
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "batch_subscription_role" {
  # Azure Batch requires this once created in UserSubscription mode
  scope                            = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
  principal_id                     = data.azuread_service_principal.batch_spn.object_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

It's a shame I cannot hardcode SPN because it is different on each tenant (unlike AzBatch application ID)

Comment: No, there isn't a direct way to force Azure Active Directory to register an enterprise application for Azure Batch before the Batch Account is created. The registration of service principals typically occurs during the creation of associated resources, and Batch might not have a service principal until the Batch Account is provisioned.

Comment: so what you're saying is that I'm stuck with weird mambo-jumbo of spawning whatever AzBatchAccount just to make "real" terraform proceed infra with account configuration I want?